# Calling screen manager from custom button within custom layout

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm building a photo viewing app that uses kivy and google photos api.  I'm using a custom StackView within a screen to iterate through albums to create a button for each album. I'm using a custom AsyncImage, ButtonBehavior class to simplify the button's source image. I'm having issues trying to call the screen manager's current property.  I know within a kv file I can call root, or from python I can use self.manager.current = ... I'm not sure how to go about calling the manager from a few levels down. Here's the relevant code.

How to I switch screens from ImageButton's on_press or on release function?

```
class AlbumScreen(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):

    def switch_screen(self, screen):
        self.current = screen

class AlbumStack(StackLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AlbumStack, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        creds = get_credentials()
        svc = build_service(creds)
        albums = get_albums(svc)
        self.orientation = 'lr-tb'
        self.spacing = 2
        self.padding = 4
        params = '=w200-h200-c'
        try:
            for album in albums:
                url = parametrize_url(album['coverPhotoBaseUrl'], params)
                btn = ImageButton(source=url,size=(100,100), size_hint=(None,None))
                self.add_widget(btn)
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))


class ImageButton(AsyncImage, ButtonBehavior):
    pass
```

and the relevant portion of my kv file

```
<WindowManager>:
    LoginScreen:
    AlbumScreen:
    PictureSelectorScreen:
    PictureViewerScreen:

<AlbumScreen>:
    name: 'AlbumScreen'
    AlbumStack:
```

EDIT:

I was able to get this working by adding overriding the custom buttons on_release:

```
class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, AsyncImage):

    def on_release(self):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        app.root.switch_screen('PictureViewerScreen')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply refer to the app widget in kvlang.

Assuming your WindowManager is the root widget, i.e.

```
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return WindowManager()
```

you can switch screens (and specify a transition direction) directly inside the .kv file:

```
....
    ImageButton:
        on_release: 
            app.root.current = 'PictureViewerScreen'
            app.root.transition.direction = 'right'
....
```